# Print notebook with all cells opened

Tags: notebooks, pdf-format, printing, cells

I have a long *Mathematica* notebook where some cells on multiple levels are closed for clarity.

When I export the notebook as a *PDF* via `Print` or `Save as`, the print only contains the opened cells.

I want to be able to print all cells - even the closed ones - into the *PDF*.
When I open them via `Cell -> Grouping -> Open all Subgroups` my actual notebook is changed destructively, and I have to re-close certain groups by hand because there's no proper undo.

Did I miss any option?

Comment: Quick an dirty: save your notebook in the desired state, open all cells, print and then revert to the saved notebook?

Comment: @YvesKlett Pity, that you didn't put your comment as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I hoped there was a much more elegant solution to this - I don't have the feeling that I'm trying to achieve something extravagant here. Hopefully Mathematica 10 will improve this.

Answer (score 3):

Another quick(?) and dirty way:

Let `nb` be the notebook to be printed. E.g., execute `nb = EvaluationNotebook[]` in the notebook you would like.  Then execute

```
NotebookPrint[NotebookGet@nb /. CellGroupData[data_, Closed] :> CellGroupData[data, Open]]
```

or

```
Export["/tmp/foo.pdf", 
 NotebookGet@nb /. CellGroupData[data_, Closed] :> CellGroupData[data, Open]]
```

One potential drawback is that `NotebookGet` essentially creates a copy of the notebook (I assume).

There is probably a way to make it more automatic.  Others here are more fluent in manipulating notebooks than I am.  I have had this problem, but I cannot find or recall how I dealt with it.  Perhaps as Yves suggested in a comment: save the notebook, open all cells, print, and revert to saved.